# Display two MySQL selects in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a form where a user can enter a age and select a gender, this then returns all data over this specific age with that specific gender.

This is the SQL query I have to find this data:

```
 if($_POST['sRetrieve1']) 
    $queryRetrieve = mysql_query( "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) 
    AS sBirthday FROM staffData WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) > 
    '".$_POST['qRetrieveAge']."' AND sGender='".$_POST['qRetrieveGender']."'");
```

This is then printed out via

```
echo ' <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">';
echo ' <thead> ';
echo ' <tr> ';
echo '      <th>Gender</th> ';
echo '      <th>Fullname</th> ';
echo '      <th>Age</th> ';
echo '      <th>Job Title</th> ';
echo '      <th>Email</th> ';
echo '      <th>Contact no.</th> ';
echo '      <th>Address</th> ';
echo '      <th>Date Joined</th> ';
echo ' </tr> ';
echo ' </thead> ';
echo ' <tbody> ';

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRetrieve, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        { 

echo ' <tr> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sGender"].'';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sFN"].'';
echo '    &nbsp'.$info["sSN"].'';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sBirthday"].'</td> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sJobTitle"].'';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sEmail"].'</td>';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sPhone"].'</td> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sAddress"].'</td> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["sDateJoined"].'</td> ';
echo ' </tr> ';
}
```

But this is only display the sBirthday, how would I make it so the other fields are field in?

[image]

- the reason I can't just do `select *` is because sBirthday field is originally just a birthday, hence why the calculation is needed to work out the age.

Comment: you haven't put any other field in your query. it will only return the data you ask of it, nothing more

Comment: @Dagon sorry i should have mentioned, how would i put the other fields in? ive tried a separate query but then it echos the birthDATE instead of age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add in the fields you want to select like so:

```
$queryRetrieve = mysql_query( "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) 
AS sBirthday,sGender, sFN [ALL THE REST] FROM staffData WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) > 
'"

.$_POST['qRetrieveAge']."' AND sGender='".$_POST['qRetrieveGender']."'");
```

replace [ALL THE REST] with the list of fields separated by commas

in case you still want to use *  (but its usually better not to) you can just do this:

```
$queryRetrieve = mysql_query( "SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) 
AS sBirthdayXXXXX  FROM staffData WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sBirthday, CURDATE()) > 
'"

.$_POST['qRetrieveAge']."' AND sGender='".$_POST['qRetrieveGender']."'");
```

then just change

```
echo '    <td>'.$info["sBirthday"].'</td> ';
```

to

```
echo '    <td>'.$info["sBirthdayXXXXX"].'</td> ';
```